# Enterprise Wiki security boundaries

Tags: sharepoint-online, security, security-trimming, enterprise-wiki

What is the prefered way to handle security boundaries in a Wiki?

We're about to start documenting our business processes in a wiki. We would like to be able to tag our group wiki pages as a security boundary so some groups only have access to certain tags/groups of pages and so on.

Is this possible and recommended? Or do we have to have a separate wiki for each security group?

What's best practise in this case?

Comment: Am i over simplifying this by thinking this is as easy as setting target audience in each pages property?

Comment: Not really, I'm just unsure about performance reprecussions or if there's a better way to do it? Usually the advice is not to break permission inheritance unless necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you just set individual permissions for any pages that require it. The best method is to create security groups in SharePoint, disinherit the parent permissions on any relevant pages, and then specify the security groups that can access and edit the pages.

To do this,

1. Go to any wiki page and then click **Page** to open the ribbon menu
2. Click **Page Permissions**.
3. On the permissions page, click **Stop Inheriting Permissions**.
4. Then click **Grant Permissions** to grant a custom security group (or specific users) permissions or click **Create Group** to quickly create a new security group.

Comment: Thanks, there are no particular performance repercussions in doing this?

Comment: I honestly can't speak to that. I mean, if you have hundreds or thousands of pages, then yeah it will probably have an effect. But again, I work mostly on the front end and don't want to give you bad info. One thing you might consider though is grouping all of the pages that have the same security permissions to minimize the impact

Comment: Grouping sounds like what I would want to do, but how do one do that? I thought the wiki in itself was the only container?